# How to initialize resources inside a project referenced by ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core

I have two projects: `Lib` (class library) and `Ui` (ASP.NET Core) whereby `Lib` is referenced by `Ui` by adding it as a project reference.

`Lib` has a `Resources\foo.json` file that is read by one of `Lib`'s classes. The file is marked as a `Content` and `Copy always`. However, `Ui` complains that it cannot find the path to the file.

I can move the `foo.json` to `Ui` but it doesn't make a good design as the `Lib` should be the one handling it.

Comment: You need to provide a fully reproducible example.

Comment: Instead of marking the `foo.json` file in Lib as `Content` and `Copy always`, you should mark it as an `Embedded Resource`. This tells the compiler to embed the file within the assembly, making it accessible as an embedded resource.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it thanks to @AmitMohanty's suggestion:

"Instead of marking the foo.json file in Lib as Content and Copy always, you should mark it as an Embedded Resource. This tells the compiler to embed the file within the assembly, making it accessible as an embedded resource."

Answer (score 0):

Your `UI` project doesn't have access to files from `Lib`. If - as you say - `Lib` has to handle it, then how come you have references to it in `UI`.

Find where `UI` references the file and fix it.

Comment: Ui creates Lib and calls its methods but Lib does the setup

Comment: "Ui creates Lib" - don't know what it means; those are two projects in solution. "calls its methods but Lib does the setup" - exactly! You should call Lib method without referring to a file directly. If UI is trying to find path to file - find it and fix it!

Comment: Ui is the view. Lib is the model. View is dumb. Lib is the workhorse. View contains a reference to model because Ui creates the Lib. Lib uses Path.Combine("Resources", "foo.json") but Ui creates a /ui/Resources/foo.json" path but the correct path is /ui/../lib/resources/foo.json". How to get this path?

Comment: By creating API in LIB that returns JSON from the file; **not** path to the file that is not accessible to UI. Then you can invoke the API from UI